# SetText of EditText NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am trying to set the text of my EditText, but I am getting a null pointer exception. I have seen other posts answering this question, however I am extending ActionBarActivity so I can not simply solve this problem by using something like EditText f1 = (EditText) **getActivity()**.findViewById(R.id.field1);

```
public class SwitchURL extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_switch_url);



        Intent intent = getIntent();
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        EditText f1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.field1);
        EditText f2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.field2);

        SharedPreferences pref1 = getSharedPreferences("textField1", 0);
        SharedPreferences pref2 = getSharedPreferences("textField1", 0);
        Log.v("", pref1.getString("textField1", "DNE"));
        Log.v("", pref2.getString("textField2", "DNE"));

        f1.setText("hello", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);


        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }

    }
```

I know I am getting the NullPointerException because I am not accessing the right view that contains this editText. I have a method that is called when a button is clicked and it works fine.

```
public void changeUrl(View v) {
    EditText f1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.field1);
    EditText f2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.field2);

    SharedPreferences pref1 = getSharedPreferences("textField1", 0);
    SharedPreferences pref2 = getSharedPreferences("textField1", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit1 = pref1.edit();
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit2 = pref2.edit();

    edit1.putString("textField1", f1.getText().toString());
    edit2.putString("textField2", f2.getText().toString());
    edit1.commit();
    edit2.commit();

    Log.v("", pref1.getString("textField1", "Fail"));
    Log.v("", pref2.getString("textField2", "Fail"));   
}
```

Any idea how I can access this view so that I can set the text of my editText? Here is the xml:

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.android_native.SwitchURL$PlaceholderFragment"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/contain" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/urlScreenTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Change URL" 
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/field1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:text="http://stage1.onshift.com"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:background="@drawable/switch_url_fields_background"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:paddingLeft="7dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/field2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:text="http://stage.v2.onshift.com"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:background="@drawable/switch_url_fields_background"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
        android:paddingLeft="7dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/switchUrlButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:text="Change URL"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:background="@drawable/switch_url_button"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="changeUrl"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i assume the field is in the fragment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like you are trying to access views defined in the fragment's layout from within the activity. The activity doesn't know about the fragment layout at creation. Move your code which is getting the views and managing their content into the fragment's onCreatView().

Answer (score 1):

If the EditText is inside of a Fragment, then when your Activity is created the Fragment has not been created yet and has not had it's Views inflated yet. Attempting to access any of its Views at this time with `findViewById()` will return `null`.

Your code for accessing Views of the Fragment belongs in `onCreateView` or in `onViewCreated` of the Fragment class itself, not inside of `onCreate` of the Activity. You should also put all of your logic in the Fragment, so that you can better modularize your code.